# How to stop all images displaying in an image modal?

Tags: javascript, html, json, modal-dialog, gallery

I am creating an image gallery which displays a modal of the image and some additional information when clicked. The data is drawn from an embedded json string. The modal displays the correct image in a large frame but also displays the other images underneath. How can I prevent the other images displaying?

Many thanks!

This is the JSON:

```
var json = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1","img":"https://img1.etsystatic.com/029/0/9428797/il_340x270.597883049_nole.jpg"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2","img":"https://img1.etsystatic.com/035/1/9428797/il_340x270.597881301_g3hw.jpg"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2","img":"https://img0.etsystatic.com/026/0/9428797/il_340x270.597777722_o6wf.jpg"}];
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="newTable">
 <a href=""></a>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
 <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
```

This is putting the JSON in the div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var figure;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        figure = $('<a/>');
        figure.append("<a>"+ " <img src='"+ json[i].img+"'/>" + "</a>");
        figure.append("<a>" + json[i].User_Name + "</a>");
        figure.append("<tag>" + " " + json[i].User_Name + " " + json[i].score + " " + json[i].team + " " + "</tag>");
        $('div').append(figure);
    }
});
```

And this is the modal:

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

```
var modalImg = $("#img01");

$(document).ready(function(){    
 $("img").click(function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  var newSrc = this.src;
  modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
  }); 
});   

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with CSS.

```
    <html>
    #modal{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    }

    </html>
```

You are putting modal.style.display="block". I suggest you change it to none.

Comment: Thank you @Samanja09 I don't think I was clear about what I wanted. I have made a jsfiddle to be clearer - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/q8og8pmx/). You will see that when you click on an image you get a larger version in the modal but also the other images underneath. I want these images to be hidden. Setting modal.style.display to "none" hides the whole modal.